# Appium breaking on switching to webview

Tags: android, webview, appium

I've read all that I could find, tried all that crossed my mind and I'm still stuck at this thing. So, working on a hybrid app, it has landing screen (fully native) with a button that opens a webview. After I switch to a web view in order to try and target an element, appium brakes. Does anyone have similar problems? Or any advice or solution?

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void randomTest() throws InterruptedException{

        driver.findElement(By.id("com.something.something:id/activate")).click(); //This is native part     

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.something.something"); //here it brakes (and NOT EVERY time, sometimes it passes this point, but lets say once in 10 times it passes..)
        Thread.sleep(100);
        //Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.className("button")).isDisplayed());
}
```

Appium reports that device is not visible (adb still can see it)
Appium reports this (among other stuff):

```
Available contexts: 
[debug] ["WEBVIEW_com.something.something","WEBVIEW_com.something.something"
[debug] Available contexts:
NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_com.something.something,WEBVIEW_com.something.something
[debug] Connecting to chrome-backed webview
 value: { message: 'unknown error: Device KR7A3P92LS is not online\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845.......
```

And then after bunch of other stuff, says:

```
Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device KR7A3P92LS is not online
```

Help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Reason: This happens when chromedriver become unreachable while switching to or from webview and appium keeps on waiting for response from chromedriver.

Solution: Monitor chromedriver, kill/restart it whenever it hangs.

Detailed Answer Available at: [Appium (v1.4.16.1), Switch to WebView fails when i try a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115151/appium-v1-4-16-1-switch-to-webview-fails-when-i-try-a-second-time/35123585#35123585)

Comment: Well, yes, that's what i read from appium report, and i tried that approach you are advising me to before, didn't work for me..
   'code' ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().stop(); 'code'
method is deprived..
And when you actually use them, it reports error about threads:
    'code' Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject 'code'
Tho it still works(with that error), doesn't make changes, tests again fail at point where im trying to switch to webview.
But thanks for answer. :)

Comment: @BojanAntić: Sorry for not letting you know about dependencies: you need to add these to your project: apache's httpclient-4.3.1.jar, httpcore-4.3.jar and json simple jar: json-20080701.jar and .stop() is just throwing a warning, it won't stop you from execution. Please try this and let me know if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i had those already, and appium is still failing. The worst part is that i cant figure out pattern of fails.. I though that it'll manage to switch to webview always after i start appium, and next ones are if'y.. But them, i just started appium, and on first test he didn't manage to switch context. Although it is not good even if i have to restart appium EVERY time i plan on running test since they are suppose to run on remote server via jenkins.

Comment: If your appium server and chromedriver is running on some remote machine Then you need to run the code ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().start() on the same server. Try this and let me know, also paste the logs as gist.

Comment: Yes, start() in BeforeTest and stop() in afterTest()

Comment: Im still trying to make this work only on my pc.. So i have 
    ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().start();
in my BeforeTest, i have :
    ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().stop();
in my AfterTest, i have dependencies set as advised, and still working the same.. Failing more then passing..

Comment: Can you post the server log, I suspect its not because of chromedriver then, may be something else.

Comment: @BojanAntić: is it fixed ?